# How to create sidebar using html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing a project for school but i'm having trouble structuring the website and creating a static sidebar that loads on every page.

The final product should look like this. I'm struggling to get those 2 sidebars on the left and right.

[image]

I will paste my HTML and CSS code below

```css
/*
  
  Name: 
  Date: 1/28/2018
*/

@charset "utf-8";
@import url("mp_layout.css");
html {
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
img, object, embed, video {
 max-width: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 81.9%;
 padding-left: 4.55%;
 padding-right: 4.55%;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 min-height: 100%;
}
h1 {
 font-weight: normal; 
}
h2 {
 font-weight: normal;
}
Nav a{
 text-decoration: none; /*removes underlining */
}
body > header {
 background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206)
}
nav {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 margin: 6% 2% 0% 0%;
}
article {
 width: 73%;
 float: left;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 text-align: left;
}

nav ul li {
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 8%;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
 color: rgb(167, 175, 28);
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
 color: rgb(167, 175, 28);
}
nav ul li a:focus {
 outline: thin dotted;
 color: rgb(167, 175, 28)
}
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
 outline: 0;
 color: rgb(167, 175, 28)
}
body h1 {
 margin: 1%;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

body article h1 {
 font-size: 1.15em;
}

header img {
 float: none;
 width: 96%;
 margin: 2% 2% 0% 2%;
}
body p, body address {
 margin: 3.5% 1%;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 height: 100%;
}
dl {
 margin-left: 2%;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
dt {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 text-indent: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 168, 168,1.00);
}
dd {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 3% 3%;
 text-indent: 0;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: black;
 background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
 margin-top: 4%;
 border-top: 3px outset #cf7b79;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 clear: both;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
}

article aside h1 {
 display: none;
}

article div {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
}

article div:first-of-type {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

article div h1 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

article p, article address {font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
/* =============================================
 Tablet layout styles used by devices
 481px to 768px and cascaded to larger 
 devices.
   =============================================
*/


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
html, body {
 font-size: 16px;
}

body {
 width: 89.9%;
 padding-left: 1.55%;
 padding-right: 1.55%;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
}

header h1 {
   font-size: 2.2em;
}

body article h1 {
   font-size: 1.75em;
}

article {
 width: 94%;
 float: none;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
dl#ct_locations {
 width: 57%;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
dl {
 width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
}
article img {
 float: right;
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0% 2% 2% 2%;
}
nav ul li {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 15%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 2%;
 border: thin solid rgba(127,96,17,1.00);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
nav ul li a {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav {
 display: table;
 width: 96%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
}
nav ul {
 display: table-row;
 margin: 0;
}
nav ul li:last-of-type {
 margin-right: 0%;
}

article ul {
 margin-top: -20px;
}

article aside {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
 padding: 5%;
 border: 1px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);
 width: 15%;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 background-color: #cecece;
}

article aside h1 {
 display: block;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111, 111, 111);
}

article div {
 float: left;
 width: 30.3%;
 margin: 0% 1% 2% 1%;
 border: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
}

article div:first-of-type {
 margin-top: 0%;
}

article div h1 {
 text-align: right;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
 background-color: #ffdcdb;
}

article div p {
 font-size: 0.85em;
 text-align: left;
}

footer {
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
}



/* =============================================
 Desktop layout styles used by  devices
 769px and larger.
   =============================================
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
html, body {
 font-size: 20px;
}

html {
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /*change browser background color */
 margin: 0px auto;
}
body {
 width: 88.2%;
 max-width: 900px;
 padding-left: 0.9%;
 padding-right: 0.9%;
 margin: 0px auto auto auto;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 background-color: white; /* <-- Change body background color */
 -moz-box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px,  rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px,  rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
 box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px,  rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
}

article div h1 {
 font-size: 1.1em;
}

article div p {
 font-size: 0.95em;
}

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <!--  - 1/15/2017 -->
 <title>Mobile Panini</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="Italian, Mobile, food, Charlotte" />
 <link href="mp_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Limelight" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 
</head>
 

<body>
 <header>
  <a href="mp_index.html"><img src="banner.png" alt="Mobile Panini" /></a>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="mp_index_txt.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="mp_courses_txt.html">Courses</a></li>
       <li><a href="mp_about_txt.html">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="mp_terms_txt.html">Terms</a></li>
       <li><a href="mp_feedback_txt.html">Feedback</a></li>
       <li><a href="mp_help_txt.html">Help</a></li>
     
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <article>
  <h1>Child & Youth Care</h1>
  <img src="mp_photo1.png" alt="" />
  <p><strong>Mobile Panini</strong> is the culmination of the dream of Antonio and Carmen
Dolcini, who came to America looking to serve people the
authentic recipes learned from their Sicilian family.</p>

  <p>Antonio began work as a child in his grandmother's deli where he
learned the age-old secrets of Sicilian cooking. He refined his
technique at the Culinary Institute of Milan. His younger brother,
Carmen, with no less of a love for cooking and good food, also
worked in the deli and became well-acquainted with the open-air
fresh food markets of his home town. Carmen too, is a proud
graduate of the Culinary Institute of Milan.</p>

  <p>Now you can enjoy what they have learned and mastered, right outside 
your door; but with no compromises in freshness or delicacy of preparation.
We've partnered with <em>Curbside Thai</em> to bring you the finest cuisine on 
four wheels - from the East and the West!</p> 

<p> Phone: <a href="tel:+1 (704) 555-2188" >+1 (704) 555-2188 </a></p>

<p>E-mail: <a href="mobilepanini@panini.com" >mobilepanini@panini.com</a></p>



 </article>
 <footer>
  Douglas College : 700 Royal Avenue, New Westminster : 604-527-5400
 </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is wrap your existing `<article>` inside of a `<div>` element that will become your `right` column (`<div class="right">`). Then you want to create a second `<div>` just before this wrapper, that will become the `left` column (`<div class="left">`). Both of these columns should **[`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)** to the left, and should have a set **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)**. I've gone with a width of `20%` for the smaller column and `80%` for the larger column.

```
.left {
  width: 20%;
}
.right {
  width: 80%;
}
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
}
```

Note that you'll want to place all of these rules inside of your media query for desktop-only views, so that the columns still stack on mobile.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
/*
  
  Name: 
  Date: 1/28/2018
*/

@charset "utf-8";
@import url("mp_layout.css");
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

img,
object,
embed,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 81.9%;
  padding-left: 4.55%;
  padding-right: 4.55%;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

Nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*removes underlining */
}

body>header {
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206)
}

nav {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 6% 2% 0% 0%;
}

article {
  width: 73%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: left;
}

nav ul li {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

nav ul li a:visited {
  color: rgb(167, 175, 28);
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  color: rgb(167, 175, 28);
}

nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  color: rgb(167, 175, 28)
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  outline: 0;
  color: rgb(167, 175, 28)
}

body h1 {
  margin: 1%;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body article h1 {
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

header img {
  float: none;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2% 2% 0% 2%;
}

body p,
body address {
  margin: 3.5% 1%;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 100%;
}

dl {
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

dt {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 168, 168, 1.00);
}

dd {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 3% 3%;
  text-indent: 0;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
  margin-top: 4%;
  border-top: 3px outset #cf7b79;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

article aside h1 {
  display: none;
}

article div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
}

article div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

article div h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

article p,
article address {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}


/* =============================================
 Tablet layout styles used by devices
 481px to 768px and cascaded to larger 
 devices.
   =============================================
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  body {
    width: 89.9%;
    padding-left: 1.55%;
    padding-right: 1.55%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
  }
  body article h1 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }
  article {
    width: 94%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  dl#ct_locations {
    width: 57%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
  dl {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
  article img {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 2%;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border: thin solid rgba(127, 96, 17, 1.00);
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav {
    display: table;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  article ul {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  article aside {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    padding: 5%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #cecece;
  }
  article aside h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111, 111, 111);
  }
  article div {
    float: left;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin: 0% 1% 2% 1%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
  }
  article div:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  article div h1 {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
    background-color: #ffdcdb;
  }
  article div p {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: left;
  }
  footer {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}


/* =============================================
 Desktop layout styles used by  devices
 769px and larger.
   =============================================
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  html {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    /*change browser background color */
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  body {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: 0px auto auto auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    background-color: white;
    /* <-- Change body background color */
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px, rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px, rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
    box-shadow: rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) 20px 0px 25px, rgba(31, 61, 31, 0.9) -20px 0px 25px;
  }
  article div h1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  article div p {
    font-size: 0.95em;
  }
  .left {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .right {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .left,
  .right {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="mp_index.html"><img src="banner.png" alt="Mobile Panini" /></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="mp_index_txt.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="mp_courses_txt.html">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="mp_about_txt.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="mp_terms_txt.html">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="mp_feedback_txt.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="mp_help_txt.html">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="left">
    LEFT-HAND CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <article>
      <h1>Child & Youth Care</h1>
      <img src="mp_photo1.png" alt="" />
      <p><strong>Mobile Panini</strong> is the culmination of the dream of Antonio and Carmen Dolcini, who came to America looking to serve people the authentic recipes learned from their Sicilian family.</p>

      <p>Antonio began work as a child in his grandmother's deli where he learned the age-old secrets of Sicilian cooking. He refined his technique at the Culinary Institute of Milan. His younger brother, Carmen, with no less of a love for cooking and good
        food, also worked in the deli and became well-acquainted with the open-air fresh food markets of his home town. Carmen too, is a proud graduate of the Culinary Institute of Milan.</p>

      <p>Now you can enjoy what they have learned and mastered, right outside your door; but with no compromises in freshness or delicacy of preparation. We've partnered with <em>Curbside Thai</em> to bring you the finest cuisine on four wheels - from the
        East and the West!</p>

      <p> Phone: <a href="tel:+1 (704) 555-2188">+1 (704) 555-2188 </a></p>

      <p>E-mail: <a href="mobilepanini@panini.com">mobilepanini@panini.com</a></p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Douglas College : 700 Royal Avenue, New Westminster : 604-527-5400
  </footer>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much . I still have a small question. Where would the "About Peter Craft" section go?

Comment: For that I would recommend applying the exact same principle -- simply divide your `<article>` up into another two `<div>` elements, another `left` and `right`. Then just give each a width of say `50%` and `float` them next to each other :)

Comment: I tried doing it but it's not proportionate....It puts each <div> element under each other instead of side by side

Comment: I figured it out. I was missing a <div> element. Thank you Obsidian :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the html

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

            <div class="header">
                <div class="header-inside">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                            <span>First</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#mycollapsable" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <span>Second</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="mycollapsable" class="collapse">
                            <ul>
                                <li>asjd</li>
                                <li>dasd</li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>

                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-content">

            </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    direction:rtl;
}


body{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-right:200px;
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    direction:rtl;

}

.container{

    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:gray;
}

.header{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:50px;
    top:0px;
    margin-right:200px;
    box-shadow:0 10px 10px gray;
}

.header .header-inside{
    position:fixed;

    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:0px;
    background-color:red;

}

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    right:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;

    background-color:blue;
}


.sidebar .navigation ul {

    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align:right;
    list-style:none;

}

.sidebar .navigation ul li{

    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    height:60px;
}


.sidebar .navigation ul li a{

    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration:none;


}

.sidebar .navigation ul li a:hover{

    background-color:red;


}


.sidebar .navigation ul li a span{

    position:absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:2em;

}

.inner-content{

    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

.inner-content .inner-content-2{
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:25px;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:red;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind most of the advice I can give you is mainly web 1.0 basic HTML.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.example/"><img src="/example.gif"></a></li> <center><a href="http://example.example">example</a></center>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  
  
</ul>
```